# Calculate the base of power function

Tags: java, math

Given function:

```
 y=power(x, z)
```

Where y is the base x raised to the power of z.

In Java and many other language, there is function Math.pow() to calculate this.

My question is: how to calculate x, given y and z? Is there a standard library function for this?

Comment: It sounds like you just want `power(y, 1/z)`.

Comment: apply log on both sides and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done easily enough by remembering a  mathematical law:

- x<sup>ab</sup> = (x<sup>a</sup>)<sup>b</sup>

And now because z*(1/z)=1, the inverse of raising to the power z is raising to the power 1/z. So in your case

- x = y<sup>1/z</sup>

Once you've got your `power()` function, that's all you need.